# How to get values of the selected table cell from datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

This my Jquery:

```
var oTable_salary = $('#jsontable_salary').dataTable();  //Initialize the datatable
$("#btn_ca_salary").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'proc_php/get_salary.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(s){
            oTable_salary.fnClearTable();
            for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
             oTable_salary.fnAddData([
                        s[i][0],
                        s[i][1],
                        s[i][2],
                        s[i][3]                                     
                               ]);                                      
            } // End For                                            
        },
        error: function(e){
           alert(e.responseText);   
        }
        });
});
```

[image]

I want to get the id from the datable when it is selected. I came up with this but it doesn't work:

```
$('#jsontable_salary tbody tr').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rowIndex =  $(this).closest('td')[0].text;
    alert(rowIndex);
});
```

Comment: You need event delegation as the elements are loaded dynamically. Try: `$('#jsontable_salary').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
var rowIndex =  $(this).find('td').first().text()
```

your attempt with *closest* doesn't work, as closest traverses the DOM upwards

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) at this context since we are trying to retrieve the `td` value from the click event of its parent `tr`,

```
$('#jsontable_salary').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var rowIndex =  $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    alert(rowIndex);
});
```

Elements that are getting loaded during the run time must use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in order to attach an event with it.